# MySQL order by optimization with joins and wheres

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  DISTINCT `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `photos`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `albums_photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `albums_photos`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_tags` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_tags`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_comments` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_comments`.`id` 
WHERE (`photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') 
AND (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL) 
ORDER BY `photos`.`date_taken` DESC 
LIMIT 75 
OFFSET 0
```

It takes which takes 6-7 sec to run. When I take out the Order by clause:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  DISTINCT `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `photos`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `albums_photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `albums_photos`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_tags` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_tags`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_comments` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_comments`.`id` 
WHERE (`photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') 
AND (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL) 
LIMIT 75 
OFFSET 0
```

It takes 0.025 sec to run. So clearly something is not optimized.
I have these indices on photos

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part, Packed, Null, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment
photos, 0, PRIMARY, 1, id, A, 21069, , , , BTREE, , 
photos, 1, index_photos_on_location_id, 1, location_id, A, 468, , , YES, BTREE, , 
photos, 1, index_photos_on_date_taken, 1, date_taken, A, 21069, , , YES, BTREE, , 
photos, 1, index_photos_on_status, 1, status, A, 2, , , YES, BTREE, , 
photos, 1, index_photos_on_phash, 1, phash, A, 21069, , , YES, BTREE, ,
```

Photos is set up as per:

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, bigint(20), NO, PRI, , auto_increment
date_taken, datetime, YES, MUL, , 
created_at, datetime, NO, , , 
updated_at, datetime, NO, , , 
file_extension, varchar(255), YES, , , 
file_size, int(11), YES, , , 
location_id, bigint(20), YES, MUL, , 
make, varchar(255), YES, , , 
model, varchar(255), YES, , , 
original_height, int(11), YES, , , 
original_width, int(11), YES, , , 
longitude, decimal(16,10), YES, , , 
latitude, decimal(16,10), YES, , , 
status, int(11), YES, MUL, 0, 
phash, varchar(255), YES, MUL, , 
org_id, int(11), YES, , , 
lg_id, int(11), YES, , , 
md_id, int(11), YES, , , 
tm_id, int(11), YES, , ,
```

what can I do. Should I do the ordering in my app (rails or JS)?

-- EDIT --

I should add that when I take out all the joins but leave in the order by the time drops to below a sec. Makes me think I need an index across the joined columns and date_taken??

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  DISTINCT `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
WHERE (`photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') 
AND (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL) 
#AND (`photos`.`date_taken` is not null)
ORDER BY `photos`.`date_taken` DESC 
LIMIT 75 
OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: how many rows you have in tables?  .. the photos.id is auto_increment ?(each row have a diffrerent id ? )

Comment: added the table definition. Yes it is auto_increment. I have 21000 rows and growing...

Comment: There's an article on explainextended about late row lookups. Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the tables contains a pk (eg:  an id auto_increment) the `distinct photos.*` is unuseful
each row id different from the others

remove unuseful () in where condition

and remember that the limit is applied  after al the rows are retrieved  and ordered  by  (for this try removing limit and offset for test)

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE   `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `photos`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `albums_photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `albums_photos`.`photo_id` 
LEFT JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
LEFT JOIN `source_tags` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_tags`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `source_comments` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_comments`.`id` 
WHERE `photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24'
AND  (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL) 
ORDER BY `photos`.`date_taken` DESC 
LIMIT 75 
OFFSET 0
```

be sure you have proper index on all the join columun and foreign key
and over all a proper index on `photos.date_taken`  and `photos.status`

you could use also a composite index `(photos.date_taken ,photos.status)`

Comment: It was the distinct clause...I added that because I was getting duplicates due to the joins. That was an overall lousy fix - should have worked more with the joins.

Comment: When you say to have proper index on join columns, you mean to have e.g. and index on facets.photo_id, right?

Comment: Yes  ...but remember the index involved  in where clause too  ..this is primarly invoke for reduce the set of row used in join  ..

Comment: Well I can't just take away the distinct because I have several rows in facets with the same photo_id. I have added the indexes and FK's, but can't seem to progress performance...how can I analyse this?

Comment: A first suggestion if you have several rows in facets . that generated  duplicated  rows  then join the select distinct form this table only joining a subquery .   For see the use of the index  by the sql engine  take a look at explain plan

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.Faced a similar issue and fixed it like this.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  DISTINCT `photos`.* 
FROM `photos` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `photos`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `albums_photos` ON `photos`.`id` = `albums_photos`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facets` ON `photos`.`id` = `facets`.`photo_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_tags` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_tags`.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `source_comments` ON `facets`.`source_id` = `source_comments`.`id` 
WHERE (`photos`.`date_taken` <= '2017-08-24') 
AND (photos.status != 1 or photos.status is NULL)
)ORDER BY `photos`.`date_taken` DESC 
LIMIT 75 
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. When you order by the primary key of photos table, would this execute faster than this?